# Weird Angular Binding Issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a weird angularjs binding problem

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Application (Environment: {{ globalConfig.environment + ""}})</a>
```

That will work, and render the value "dev"

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Application (Environment: {{ globalConfig.environment }})</a>
```

This doesn't render anything.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Application (Environment: <span ng-bind="globalConfig.environment"></span>)</a>
```

This last example works.

Any ideas why the second example won't render out the value "dev"?

The controller is as follows:

```
angular.module('uppApp').controller('globalController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.globalConfig = {
        environment: 'dev'
    };
});
```

the html looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" ng-app="uppApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Pixel Pimp Web UI</title>

    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/thirdparty/ie8mediasupport.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body ng-controller="globalController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pixel Pimp (Environment: <span ng-bind="globalConfig.environment"></span>)</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">Pixel Groups</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>

        <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <script src="assets/thirdparty/built.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/uppangular.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(function () { genGraph(); });
    function genGraph() {
        new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: [
              { year: '2008', value: 20 },
              { year: '2009', value: 10 },
              { year: '2010', value: 5 },
              { year: '2011', value: 5 },
              { year: '2012', value: 20 }
            ],
            // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
            xkey: 'year',
            // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
            ykeys: ['value'],
            // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
            // chart.
            labels: ['Value']
        });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### UPDATE

When i wrap the decorate the interpolate service for debugging like this:

```
app.config(function($provide){
    $provide.decorator("$interpolate", function($delegate){

        var interpolateWrap = function(){
            var interpolationFn = $delegate.apply(this, arguments);
            if(interpolationFn) {
                return interpolationFnWrap(interpolationFn, arguments);
            }
        };

        var interpolationFnWrap = function(interpolationFn, interpolationArgs){
            return function(){
                var result = interpolationFn.apply(this, arguments);
                var log = result ? console.log : console.warn;
                log.call(console, "interpolation of  " + interpolationArgs[0].trim(), 
                                  ":", result.trim());
                return result;
            };
        };

        angular.extend(interpolateWrap, $delegate);
        return interpolateWrap;

    });
});
```

The console log will show:

```
interpolation of  {{globalConfig.environment+""}} : dev
```

However for the binding of {{globalConfig.environment}} nothing shows up in the console window.

Comment: works fine here: http://jsbin.com/tawetawesa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yeah. I've never had this issue before. It's really peculiar, there must be something screwed up somewhere in my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out.  I'm using grunt bake for the first time, and I think grunt bake, is stripping out the {{globalConfig.environment}} code from the rendered file.

Sorry.  Stupid mistake.

### UPDATE

Ultimately I fixed it by modifying the BAKE parse pattern to use [{ }] instead of {{ }}

```
bake: {
        build: {
            options: {
                parsePattern: '/\[\{\s?([\.\-\w]*)\s?\}\]/g'
            },
            files: {
                "app/index.html": "app/base.html"
            }
        }
    },
```